# How to determine which message has been delivered use eclipse paho for MQTT client.

Tags: java, mqtt

By using paho(java) to build my own MQTT client.I would like to do same actions when message is delivered.So I want to implement `MqttCallBack` and use `deliveryComplete` method.But I found that the `MqttMessage` in `MqttDeliveryToken` should be set to `null` once the message has been delivered.

so my question is that there is any way to determine which message has been sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See: http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/paho-dev/msg00099.html